# Nexus 4 shows less memory that installed in the device after removing Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, data-recovery, nexus-4

I tried to install Ubuntu Touch in nexus 4 and later I installed back cyanogenmod 11, but only 12 GB is showing as memory instead of 16 GB. I think I was not able to completely remove Ubuntu files installed in it.

What should I do so that I get back the 16 GB?

Comment: Have you tried *factory reset* install of **4.2.2** or **4.4.2**? I would still suggest **4.2.x** (JellyBean) if you intend to then install Ubuntu Touch.

Comment: In clockwordmod recovery i wiped out cache and wiped data and factory reset also the dalvicks cache..dont know what happened.is there any thing else that needs to be done??so that i will get back the full 16gb

Comment: Start with ***factory reset* install** (using Google script), which will completely wipe all partitions. *You will then need to re-install any mod/recovery.*

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you start from a pristine setup; the best option is to install the factory images, the ones for the Nexus 4 (occam/mako) are here:

https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occam

Extract the file, enter the extracted directory and run the `./flash-all.sh` command.

Afterwards you could follow the installation procedure for CyanogenMod from their guide.

The most likely cause for having less available space, given no repartitioning happened at all, is that something was not wiped from the userdata partition when moving over.

Comment: **Thanks.** I should have made my earlier comments an answer (with more details).